# Range of Expected Value

Tags: probability

The expected value can be very loosely described as the "average" of a set of values.  Therefore, intuitively, it should fall within the "covering" interval of those values.

That is, assuming a r.v. $ X > 0$ with density $f(x)$ and ${E(X)} < \infty$, then shouldn't:
$$ 0 \le \int^a_0 x\,f(x)\,dx \le a $$

Can someone help prove or disprove this?

Thanks!

**Edit**: Thanks @Robert!  The context of this is actually from Lehmann's Theory of Point Estimation.  In p.212, he defines a "scale median" as the solution to:

$$ {E(X)I(X\le c)} = {E(X)I(X\ge c)}$$

Based on the original inequality above, the left hand side would "approach" $c$ from the left, and the right hand side would "approach" $c$ from the right.  However, they will never seem to be equal.  Will just ask this in another post.  Thanks again!

Comment: The inequality you've written is true if $\int_0^a f(x)\,dx=1$.  If  $f$ is a density on some larger set, then one can look at the _contiditional_ density given that the random variable is in the interval $[0,a]$ and write $0\le\dfrac{\int_0^a xf(x)\,dx}{\int_0^a f(x)\,dx}\le a$.

Comment: The identity defining the scale median in the Edit should be $E(X;X\leqslant c)=E(X;X\geqslant c)$.

Comment: @Did, I'm just quoting from the book.  In any case, if you can, please help me with the related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316644/scale-median-for-mre-estimators-with-absolute-difference-error-function-for-scal

Comment: You are probably not quoting exactly. Note that your other question uses the condition as written in my comment, not as you wrote it here (which reads $A=A$, hence is always true).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x f(x) \le a f(x)$ for $0 \le x \le a$.

Comment: w.p. 1 or almost surely right?

Comment: @Inquest Everywhere. (Where do you see randomness in this inequality?)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- For every $x$ in $(0,a)$, $0\leqslant xf(x)\leqslant af(x)$.
- $\displaystyle\int_0^af(x)\mathrm dx\leqslant1$.